# Using taskRunSpecs for service account to clone, build, test and publish to gcp artifact library to maven failed

Tags: maven, kubernetes, gradle, tekton, tekton-pipelines

In the pipeline run, I have use `taskRunSpecs` to set the service account, the git clone is working fine, however with the GCP publish with the maven library failed with error message as

```
Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
2023-07-29T12:17:51.116212588Z    > Could not PUT 'https://australia-southeast2-maven.pkg.dev/fetebird-392007/common/fete/bird/common/0.0.0/common-0.0.0.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
2023-07-29T12:17:51.116231838Z
```

**pipeline.yaml**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: ft-common
  namespace: fetebird-tekton
spec:
  params:
    - name: repo-url
      type: string
    - name : GRADLE_IMAGE
      type: string
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-data
  tasks:
    - name: git-clone
      taskRef:
        name: git-clone
      workspaces:
        - name: output
          workspace: shared-data
      params:
        - name: url
          value: "$(params.repo-url)"
        - name: deleteExisting
          value: "true"
    - name: clean-build-publish
      taskRef:
        name: gradle
      runAfter: ["git-clone"]  # Wait until the clone is done before building the java project.
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: shared-data
      params:
        - name: TASKS
          value:
            - clean
            - build
            - test
            - publish
        - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
          value: "$(params.GRADLE_IMAGE)"
```

**pipeline-run.yaml**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: ft-common-run
  namespace: fetebird-tekton
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: ft-common
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-common-pvc
  params:
    - name: repo-url
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/common.git
    - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
      value: docker.io/library/gradle:jdk17-alpine@sha256:e80d3108c319eaeef966eefdfd075fdaa44201c8fb6730532a16555426c61dbd
  taskRunSpecs:
    - pipelineTaskName: git-clone
      taskServiceAccountName: git-service-account
    - pipelineTaskName: git-clone
      taskServiceAccountName: gcp-service-account
```

**Build.Gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.2.1"
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = GROUP
            artifactId = 'common'
            version = VERSION
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releaseURL = "artifactregistry://${LOCATION}-maven.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPOSITORY}"
            url releaseURL
        }
    }
}
```

Authentication is keep getting failed. I am doing in local env with minikube

[image]